# How to map out user actions with connected features?

Tags: gui-design, workflow, task-flow

I am dealing with a new feature for our dashboard and I am trying to map out all the user's possible actions and connect them to features we have so I could see if we are missing something and improve flows. I already have user stories created epics/tasks but I need some kind of step-by-step approach of the user so I am thinking something between customer journey/user flow and service blueprint. What kind of tool or process would you use for this exercise?

Answer (score 1):

I was going to write the tools I used but there are lots of them which would be more appealing to you and more suitable for your experiences on tools you already used.

So I found more appropriate to share the lists below already available at,

[Top-20-customer-journey-mapping-tools-an-overview](https://mopinion.com/top-20-customer-journey-mapping-tools-an-overview/)

[Best-customer-journey-mapping-tools](https://www.ngdata.com/best-customer-journey-mapping-tools/)

Hope that would help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the list! I will search through and try to find something that would suit me :)

Comment: happy you enjoyed..

Answer (score 1):

I think that the exercise **Effect Mapping** (also known as Impact Mapping) could be something for you.

**How To**

To develop an effect map you use a **hierarchical diagram** or a **mind mapping** tool and start with:

1. writing down the site/app business goals
2. connect the target groups/personas/users that is needed to fulfill the goals. Then you
3. connect the user's goals to the persona and then you
4. connect the solutions/features that support their goals.

In your case I think that you could start backward; from the feature that you have developed to the user goals (or the epics/tasks) and so on if you wish.

**More info and examples**

- A short explanation of the concept: 
  https://angner.se/services/effect-mapping/
- A simple example of a finished map: 
  https://www.impactmapping.org/example.html